# How to use first linq query in second linq query

Tags: c#, linq

How to use results from first query in second linq query. I tried with as queryable but does not work.

I am getting this error

> int' does not contain a definition for 'contains' and no extension
>   method 'contains' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be
>   found

```
var query = _FirstDAL.GetList(db =>
                            from r in db.Set<Employee>() select r);

var query2 = _SecondDAL.GetList(db =>
                    from r in query.AsQueryable()
                    join e in db.Set<EmployeeType>() on r.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
                    select  r.EmployeeName);
```

Here method description of get list

```
 public List<TResult> GetList<TResult>(Func<ISetProvider, IQueryable<TResult>> queryProvider)
```

What I tried is this

```
 var query2 = _SecondDAL.GetList(db =>
                        from r in query.AsQueryable()
                        join e in db.Set<EmployeeType>() on r.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
                        where query.Any(p=>p.Equals(r.EmployeeId))
                        select  r.EmployeeName);
```

Is this correct? But I am getting this error

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."}
```

Comment: Please show the code that has the `Contains` method in in. And also `GetList`. Will help to also explain what are `_FirstDAL` and `_SecondDAL`

Comment: Can't you use procedure instead?

Comment: I can use procedure but most of code is linq so just wondering if there is any way

Comment: I did not use any contains

Comment: They are different databases so that's why used two queries

Comment: I tried with query as described in question. Is that good way

Comment: Is it necessary to use GetList in second query??
From first query you have list then you can write linq statement that will get you data without converting first list to IQueryable what is problem in this case.
What data you get in query after first GetList ?